# Finding out the difference between two quarter periods in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to find out the difference between two quarter periods.

Data as shown below:

[image]

Any plan sold year on same quarter (Let's say Oct, Nov or Dec) and the Check Month quarter ( Let's say May, June, July) would have the same difference in the quarter periods.

Need the formula to catch the difference between two quarter periods.

Eg:

```
Plan Sold Year: 2013 Dec
Check Year: 2018 Feb
```

Difference in periods: 18 periods (including 2013 quarter period as well)

Answer (score 0):

One way of tackling your question is to work out the **Plan Sale Quarter Start Date** and **Check Quarter End Date**, then do a calculation between the two dates to work out the periods (full quarters) in between.

In my solution I used two helper columns being **PSQStart** and **CQEnd** that represent the two critical dates mentioned above.

Formulas are:

```
PSQStart =DATE($A2,FLOOR(MONTH(DATEVALUE("1/"&$B2&"/"&$A2))-1,3)+1,1)

CQEnd =DATE(D2,FLOOR(MONTH(DATEVALUE("1/"&$E2&"/"&$D2))+2,3),30)

Periods =ROUNDDOWN((H2-G2)/90,0)
```

Drag all three formulas down to apply to all rows.

You can choose to combine the first two formulas into the third one but it will make the formula too long to be easily interpreted and/or edited for future needs.

Here are the main functions used in my solution:

- **DATE()** convert `yyyy,mm,dd` into a valid date/numerical value for calculations;
- **DATEVALUE()** convert text date `dd/mmm/yyyy` into a valid date/numerical value for calculations;
- **FLOOR()** work out the start/end month for a given month;
- **ROUNDDOWN()** calculate the number of periods.

[image: Solution]

Cheers :)